# How to make mandatory for the user to enter only alphanumeric values in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input type in which i want to prevent the user only to enter **alphanumeric** values like A-a and 0-9.

I have done this :

```
$('.name_list').live('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\b]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In this i am facing issue that **tab** ,**right**,**left** and **delete** keys are not working .What more i have to add in this please help me in this .

**Updated Code**

```
$('.name_list').live('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\b]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
        var Enteted = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
        if (charCode != 9 && (charCode != 37 || Enteted !='%') && charCode!=39 && charCode != 46 && !regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In this i am facing issue that it is allowing **%** to be entered .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11532982/20126  http://stackoverflow.com/q/21280482/20126

Comment: none of these are working

Comment: `live` is deprecated, use `on` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using this condition:

```
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   //...
}
```

You need to use this condition to check, is they the tab, left arrow, right arrow or delete buttons.

```
if (key !== 9 && key != 37 && key!=39 && key != 46 && !regex.test(key)) {
```

Comment: i have updated the code please check it is allowing % on key press

Comment: how we can handle this %

Comment: Yes, use 8 instead of 46.

Comment: still the same issue it is allowing %

Comment: Don't know why... % is from shift = 16, and 53

Answer (score 0):

jQuery validate plugin

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(value);
});
```